# Problems after installing to 15.04 (only background and pointer after login)

Tags: nvidia, 15.04

I installed 15.04 to dual boot on a Dell XPS 8700 with the NVidia graphics. That was a lot of trouble but I can now boot to both. But Ubuntu just gives the background and mouse after login. I've tried most of the fixes on similar subjects and no joy. What do I try next? I see "conflicting device node" errors.

lspci says VGA Compatible controller GK104 GeForce GTX 760 rev a1

I tried the recommended driver from Nvidia but it will not install unless nouveau is removed. Nouveau seems to be hard to remove and maybe a bad idea?

LXDE works but LUbuntu and Unity do not. Something is terribly wrong with the support for the 760. I'll just use LXDE for now.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install nvidia driver.

In your case I would press Ctrl+Alt+F1, login into console and run

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
sudo reboot
```

Comment: That install ran w/o errors but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install the driver directly from the NVIDIA site. Then you'll have to remove the Nouveau driver and blacklist it ( I never know how to do this part, just google blacklisting nouveau ), after that install the NVIDIA driver, update xconfig(which you can google how to) and reboot.
I suggest doing it as I am used to: First look up everything on the internet, then try installing and if anything goes bad you can either reverse it, use links,links2,elinks or other command line web browser to help you out, or if you have done a backup before, you're safe. Hope it helps :)